# Passing IWeb element to Implicit wait function

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, appium

I'm following Page Object Model on my test suite.

I have below method to wait for an element.

```
public void WaitTillCssSelector(string elemantName, int TimefromSeconds)
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimefromSeconds));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector(elemantName)));

        }
```

Currently I'm passing `elemantName` as a string to the method.But as I'm using POM, I have already defined my `CSSSelector` as an `IwebElement` as below.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "div.wo-status-box.box-light-blue")]
public IWebElement CallPriorityTxt { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to  directly pass the `CallPriorityTxt` variable to the above `WaitTillCssSelector` method?